# Chrome Driver For Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem chrome driver in Automation Testing when i am running the code they will this and my page closed :(

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
сент. 03, 2023 9:06:45 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
сент. 03, 2023 9:06:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 114
```

And my dependencies

```
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
        <webdriver.manager.version>5.5.2</webdriver.manager.version>
        <selenium.java.version>4.10.0</selenium.java.version>
        <testng.version>7.8.0</testng.version>

        <browser>chrome</browser>
        <base.url>https://www.saucedemo.com/v1/</base.url>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdriver.manager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.java.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I haven't created a blank log file mentioned in the ChromeDriverService configuration steps. Once I created it i was not able to see this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 116, so returning the closest version found: 114
```

Above warning suggests that, the browser you are using is version `116`, and the CDP version supported by your selenium is `114`. Selenium `v4.10.0` only supports up to CDP version `114`, check below:

[image]

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

**Solution:**

1. You can simply ignore this WARN, it won't effect the execution of your code
2. If you want to get rid of this WARN, just upgrade your selenium version from `4.10.0` to `4.12.0`. Check below, latest selenium(`4.12.0`) supports `116` CDP version:

[image]